# Does clang have _ExtFloat just like it has _ExtInt?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, clang, extint

I've recently been looking into clang's `_ExtInt` feature (allows you to declare any size int) a lot and was just wondering if there is also an `_ExtFloat` which I could use to create custom size floats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not.

For reference, here is what an LLVM developer stated on Reddit when asked the same question ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/g5r3sg/the_new_clang_extint_feature_provides_exact/foakv8b)):

> We've actually discussed this, but they are incredibly difficult to specify. You need 3 different pieces of information, and they don't scale on different hardware well.
>
> In the case of integers, you can do transitions with truncations/sign extensions, with floats you'd need a large software library to convert floats of unsupported sizes.